# Запрос с унарной связью

Tags: sql, oracle

Пытаюсь вывести запрос, который отобразит отряд клетки и отряды соседних двух клеток. На рисунке 2 получилось вывести только с 1 соседней клеткой, но когда ввожу в запрос на вторую клетку, то происходит путанница. Как реализовать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чём именно заключается путаница?

Comment: *запрос, который отобразит отряд клетки и отряды соседних двух клеток.* Три отряда - нужны три копии исходной таблицы.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
select a.код_кл, 
       a.отряд_кл, 
       a.сосед_кл_1, 
       c.отряд_кл, 
       a.сосед_кл_2, 
       b.отряд_кл 
from клетки a 
join клетки c on c.код_кл=a.сосед_кл_1 
full join клетки b on b.код_кл=a.сосед_кл_2 
where a.код_кл is not null;
```

Comment: Запрос неверный, хотя и близок к правильному по сути.

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!